Can I get the name of a TypeScript class or function at compile-time?
I'm trying to transform a JavaScript class which dynamically manages other classes for use in a web-based game engine into a TypeScript class for proper type checking (or, more accurately, write a .d.ts description of said class which follows its behavior). This class is called ScriptContainer, and allows one to dynamically add or remove scripts derived from the abstract ElementScript class, the details of which aren't important for this post.
The way scripts are added and accessed via the ScriptContainer works as follows: say we have a script called HelloWorld that we want to add to the container. You would call the add method of the ScriptContainer, with the constructor HelloWorld and any parameters that need to be forwarded to said constructor as parameters:
class HelloWorld extends ElementScript {
    constructor(a, b) {
        super(/* ... */);
    }

    someMethod() { /* ... */ }
}

const scripts = new ScriptContainer(/* ... */).add(HelloWorld, /* ... */);

You'd then be able to access the newly added script as a member of the script container via the constructor's name:
scripts.HelloWorld.someMethod(/* ... */);

(or, alternatively, provide you own name for the added script like this:)
new ScriptContainer(/* ... */).add('Foo', HelloWorld, /* ... */).Foo;

And fire methods with the same name across multiple loaded scripts via this interface:
scripts.run('someMethod', /* ... */);

The biggest problem I've ran into so far in regards to properly representing this behavior via TypeScript is that I can't get a specifically typed representation of a class's name from the passed-in constructor. The closest workaround I've been able to implement so far is to make use of Symbol.toStringTag, but it's obviously not ideal:
class HelloWorld extends ElementScript {
    /* ... */
    get [Symbol.toStringTag]() { return 'HelloWorld' as const; }
}

// == .d.ts FILE =============================================================================== //

type ScriptContainer<Scripts extends Record<string, ElementScript> = {}> = {
    add<Cons extends { new(...args: any[]): ElementScript; }>(
        script: Cons,
        ...args: ConstructorParameters<Cons>
    ):  Cons extends { new(...args: any[]): infer Klass extends ElementScript; } ?
        Klass extends {  [_ in typeof Symbol.toStringTag]: infer Name extends string; } ?
        ScriptContainer<Scripts & { [_ in Name]: Klass; }> : never : never;
    add<Name extends string, Cons extends { new(...args: any[]): ElementScript; }>(
        name: Name,
        script: Cons,
        ...args: ConstructorParameters<Cons>
    ):  Cons extends { new(...args: any[]): infer Klass extends ElementScript; } ?
        ScriptContainer<Scripts & { [_ in Name]: Klass; }> : never;

    /* ... */
};

I've tried to infer the constructor name via Cons extends { name: infer Name extends string }, but the inferred Name always seems to resolve to a string and nothing else more specific.
Does anybody know a better way to do this?

There's nothing but clunky workarounds (see linked q/a above). I'd say you should only support .add('Foo', HelloWorld, /* ... */) in TypeScript, and leave the other call signature out, but it's up to you whether you want to tackle this particular beast.
